# Vimeo video embedding issue (no scaling / black areas). Example included

Tags: iframe, embed, vimeo

I'm trying to embed video movies but they are not being scaled and look like you-know-what.

In addition I'm unable to post on vimeo.com forums. Google doesn't help as well.

Here's an example, vimeo movies compared to YT ones:

http://jsfiddle.net/LYt3R/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar problem. I'm implementing a mobile web site and I want autoscaling, according the screen resolution of visitor device.

This link is interesting: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-elastic-videos/comment-page-1

And this one is a complete post:

http://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php

This solution is not perfect but is the better idea I found.

The basic CSS and HTML code is:

```
    .video-container {
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 56.25%;
padding-top: 30px;
height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}

.video-container iframe,  
.video-container object,  
.video-container embed {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}


<div class="video-container">
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/6284199?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" width="800" height="450" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```